# On what kind of condition of a compact set $K$ in the plane, $C(K)$ has a generator?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

[This problem is also being answered on Math Overflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232157/on-what-kind-of-condition-of-a-compact-set-k-in-the-plane-ck-has-a-genera?noredirect=1#comment574335_232157)

Let $K\subset \Bbb{C}$ be a compact subset,$\Bbb{C}$ is the complex plane. $C(K)$ is the space of all complex continuous functions on $K$.

$f\in C(K)$ is a generator of $C(K)$ means that $\{p(f) \big|\text{p is a polynomial in z}\}$ is dense in $C(K)$.

If $K$ is any set consisting of finite points, it is easy to check that $C(K)$ has a generator.

If $K=[0,1]$, then we know that $f(x)=x$ is a generator of $C[0,1]$ by stone-weierstrass theorem. It follows that $C(\gamma)$ has a generator for $\gamma$ that is a not closed simple curve.

If $K=S^1$,unit circle on the plane.[It has been proved that $C(S^1)$ does NOT have a generator.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670160/cs1-does-not-have-a-single-generator) It follows that $C(\gamma)$ does not have a generator for any $\gamma$ that is a simple connected curve.

If $K=\mathbb{D}$,unit disk.Using [Invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain), a similar method as in the case $K=S^1$ can be given to prove that $C(\Bbb{D})$ does NOT have a generator. Similarly, It can be proved that $C(K)$ does NOT have a generator if $K$ has an interior point in $\Bbb{C}$.

How to solve this problem if $K$ does Not have an interior point?

Answer (score 3):

One needs a continuous function from K to [0,1] which separates the points of K.  Since K is compact and [0,1] is Hausdorff this amounts to an imbedding of K in [0,1]. Thus, a necessary and sufficient condition is that K be imbeddable in I.

Comment: @user317598.Why is this condition a necessary condition?

Comment: @LiJingyang: If $C(K)$ has a generator, call it $f$, then $f : K \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded continuous function.  By rescaling and adding a constant we can assume $f : K \to [0,1]$. If $f$ is not injective, say $f(x) = f(y)$, then since $f$ generates $C(K)$ we have $g(x)=g(y)$ for all $g \in C(K)$ which is absurd.  So $f$ is injective.  An injective continuous function on a compact Hausdorff space is an imbedding.

Comment: @NateEldredge.But $f$ is a comlex-valued function.